# Put total_cov next to the mutationtypes and frequencies for easy filtering

Tags: linux, sequence, analysis

I am using Breseq to analyze my Shotgun-Data. It was pretty straight forward until now. I have an issue with filtering my data. I succeeded filtering out the intergenic/non-synonymous/nonsense mutations and I could filter by frequencies. Now I want to filter it by the coverage. However the coverage is displayed below everything instead of next to the frequencies and I don't want to filter everything out by hand.

Could you tell me a way putting the total_cov and ref_cov next to the mutation frequencies so it makes it easier for me to filter it out? Or do you have any other suggestions for making it easier to filter by coverage?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should provide the code you have. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The problem is, I have no code, that's what I am looking for.